# Meaning of "Give you this lie"

Tags: meaning

Please, what's the meaning of this dialog

**MAN:** If I'm gonna lose you, it's gonna be because of what I did, not
because I lied to you.

**WOMAN:** If I give you this lie, will you stay?

**MAN:** Well, if I stay, you'll learn it.

Comment: I question whether the last line should be "Well, if I stay, you'll earn it."  Having said that the dialog makes little sense.  The first line implies the woman might be severing ties because he did something she didn't like and then lied about it.  The second line seems to be making the leaving the man's choice.  And the third line seems like the man is granting the woman a favor by staying.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Try not to scrape questions from other sites, especially if you don't fully understand the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The woman is proposing to conditionally allow the lie to pass without consequence.

Comment: Thanky you very much for you time, Lawerence!

It means she is ready to accept the lie so he can stay?

Comment: @AndreB. I would not say "accept it" but "overlook it"—or take it at face value (even though she knows better). In other words, pretend it's the truth.

Comment: @AndreB. As Jason notes, it's not an acceptance in the sense of being 'ok' with it. It's also not forgiveness *per se*. It's simply offering to drop the penalties associated with the offence if he stays. (Or, depending on what tone you ascribe to her question, merely asking whether he *would* stay if she drops the matter about the lie.)

Answer (score -1):

'If I "give" you this lie, ...' is terrible American language.  A phrase like this means the speaker is handing a lie to the listener.  Perhaps the author meant to write 'If I FORGIVE you this lie,...', which is the construction this situation seems to scream-out-loud for, since it seems the man is the one with a lie, according to the surrounding sentences.

'If I "give" you this lie, ...' might make sense if the larger story of the relationship features "trading lies" with each other like bargaining chips, currency in their own relationship to mistreat each other at times, in exchange for a reciprocal abuse privilege.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ace Frahm! I never saw this phrase before. It seems to me that the correct sense is "If I FORGIVE you this lie" because she is trying to make him stay, even after his lie. She is hurt because he wants to leave her. He is a good person, but a bad liar; He wants to go because other things can hurt her if he stay.

Comment: I think it's used in the sense of, "I'll give you that one."  Which means, as Jason has noted, "I'll overlook it"